# multiselect picklist rerender bug?

Tags: visualforce, picklist, rerender, multi-select

I noticed strange behaviour. I have multiselect picklist  with action support. If one of values is selected 2 input fields in a page block should be rendered. 
Everything works as expected when I open the page to edit existing objects. When I open the page to create an object this formula evaluates to true.

```
 <apex:inputField value="{!sobj__c.otherField__c}" 
                                    rendered="{!CONTAINS(sobj__c.multiselect__c ,'value A')}"/>
```

If I switch to IF statement the field is not visible re-rendering however doesn't work

```
<apex:inputField value="{!sobj__c.otherField__c}" 
                                    rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(sobj__c.multiselect__c ,'value A'),true,false)}"/>
```

Howto make multiselect work for new object?

Comment: Are you rerendering the fields directly or surrounding page block?. There are some restrictions in using rendered and reRender targets as same elements

Comment: No the fields are in separate output panel containing 2 page block sections. The main issue is that the fields are visible on page load when the picklist is empty Contains evaluates to true while it shouldn't